# elasticsearch fail with error "Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed"

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When i try to index data and then do query, all is good, but if i start my app and will do query without indexing before it i get that error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:272)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$3.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:224)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteFetch(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryAndFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryAndFetchAction.java:71)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my code and settings of elasticsearch

```
    //  settings
    ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();
    settings.put("client.transport.sniff", false);
    settings.put("path.home", "/path/to/elastic/home");
    settings.put("index.number_of_replicas", 0);
    settings.put("index.number_of_shards", 1);
    settings.put("action.write_consistency", "one");

    settings.build();
    // creating of node and client
    NodeBuilder nb = new NodeBuilder().settings(settings).local(true).data(true);
    Node node = nb.node();
    Client client = node.client();


    /*
         for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
         IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter2", "tweet2", String.valueOf(i))
                .setSource(json1)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
         }
   */

       searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("twitter2")
            .setTypes("tweet2")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("user", "user0"))
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("message","message1"))
            .setExplain(true)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_AND_FETCH).setSize(200);

        SearchResponse searchRespons = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet(); // here is error
```

What is wrong in me settings?

Comment: You cant search an index/type that doesnt exist can you? By commenting out the indexing of twitter2/tweet2 you just dont have anything to search.

Comment: but i seen in path /path/to/elastic/home folders which contains indexes i create before and becouse it i suppose that it possible

Comment: do you need to set a path.data so that data is persistent to the same spot in between runs?

Comment: Now my app can find old data from elastic if before it i index something, therefore error is not in path(my opinion:)

Comment: anyone has any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the same after adding a sleep for say 10 seconds after

```
Client client = node.client();
```

I feel Elasticsearch haven't recovered the shards before you have hit the search request.
Even the admin call to "wait for yellow" should work for you