# Elasticsearch query avg SearchPhaseExecutionException

Tags: elasticsearch, average

I have an index and I wanna know the medium number of the field "comments".
Here's my (basic) query:

```
GET /prova/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs" : {
        "avg_grade" : { "avg" : { "field" : "commenti" } }
    }
}
```

But something goes wrong and the reply is:

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[T4svhJ5TTmOfY2-E4_t9YQ][prova][0]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[T4svhJ5TTmOfY2-E4_t9YQ][prova][1]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[T4svhJ5TTmOfY2-E4_t9YQ][prova][2]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[T4svhJ5TTmOfY2-E4_t9YQ][prova][3]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[T4svhJ5TTmOfY2-E4_t9YQ][prova][4]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}]",
   "status": 500
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Is the field `commenti` in more that one type? Is it always a numeric type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [elasticsearch fail with error "Failed to execute phase \[query\_fetch\], all shards failed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644182/elasticsearch-fail-with-error-failed-to-execute-phase-query-fetch-all-shards)

Comment: Also read: https://www.devmynd.com/blog/2014-2-dealing-with-failing-elasticserach-tests

Comment: Usually is a number, otherwise is an empty space

Comment: It is not a duplicate, it doesn't seem to me the same problem or however the solution isn't good for my problem,